# How to compare column data in one spreadsheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have two Excel spreadsheets.  One spreadsheet has two columns of numerical data.  Column A and column B. Column A houses company codes and Column B houses Cost Centers associated with the company codes in Column A.

Then I have this doozie of a spreadsheet with many, many columns but the only two columns I'm interested in are the Company Codes and Cost Centers.  I'm not actually matching line item by line item, on the second spreadsheet, I am looking at each and every cell in the Column which houses the cost center.  I then look on Spreadsheet 1 to make sure that cost center is valid (on the spreadsheet) and also make sure that the corresponding company code (from column B) matches as well.

Is there a way in Excel for the system to do a match of sorts?  Maybe highlighting the cells on the big spreadsheet which don't appear on the first spreadsheet with just the 2 columns?  I'm trying to be a bit more efficient, and the way I'm currently cross checking is taking forever.  Especially when we are looking at over 1000 line items.

Comment: You should use a "=MATCH" formula. Formulas can reference other workbook / worksheets. Simply put an "=iserror(" in front of it then if it has an error that means no match, and if no error then it correctly found it. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

In ponderous spreadsheet, let's say company name is in "A2" for instance. And you've got company code and cost center in "B2" and "C2" respectively.

[image: Sheet1]

Spreadsheets need to be on the same workbook, Sheet1 (big one) and Sheet2 (with codes, see below).

[image: Sheet2]

On Sheet1, having "A2" selected, you need to apply the following conditional formatting rule, **as a formula** ("Home" menu, "Conditional formatting", follow the "New rule..." dialog).

```
=ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A:$B,1,0))
```

It's important writing "B2", a relative reference, and not "$B$2" you'd get by clicking on that cell.

Pick any format you like, apply, close dialog.

Now rule applies to "A2". Copy this cell, then select the area you want (maybe A2:A20000), right click and paste only formats (a button with "%" and a paint brush on my 2010 version, YMMV). If unsure, pick "Paste special..."

For cost centers check, repeat the procedure having "C2" selected; here is the formula for conditional formatting:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0)<>C2,TRUE)
```

Copy format to the other cells.